# GET 404 when loading background image from css link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load a background image loader.gif to run between pages

With this error:

```
"POST /analyze HTTP/1.1" 200 -

"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

"GET /static/css/static/images/loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Here is my code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#child {
  line-height: 675px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: large;
  color: grey;
}

div#loading {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
  background: url(/images/loader.gif) no-repeat;
  cursor: wait;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    function loading() {
      $("#loading").show();
      $("#content").hide();
    }
    //]]&gt
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <div id="loading">
    <div id="child">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/custom.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I dont understand is how the error log shows the path as `/static/css/static/images/loader.gif`

when the path I specified was /static/images/loader.gif

the file comes from the static folder in the root directory

Directory Structure

```
root
|___Static
| |___css
| |  |___bootstrap.css
| |  |___custom.css
| |
| |___images
| |  |___loader.gif
| |  |___logo.png
| |
| |___favicon.ico
|
|___templates
| |___index.html
| |___results.html
|
|___main.py
|___requirements.txt
```

Comment: Show more info, add link to working page. Current code looks good.

Comment: Can you please show your directory structure?

Comment: Edited just now, sorry for delay ;)

Comment: Put a dot `.` before image path, i.e.  ./images/loader.gif

Comment: It might comes from your Python/HTTP environment, about the way your root folder is set up :) I don't really know where else it could comes from

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2019 09:53:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2019 09:53:25] "GET /static/css/images/loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2019 09:53:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2019 09:53:27] "GET /static/css/images/loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2019 09:53:27] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: @GauravGenius Well, it would tell to start looking from where the css file is, it won't look to the gif from the root of the directory structure...

Comment: @Alexandre Gérault I think so aswell, this code was working for me in previous tests until I upgraded some of my python/other packages, now I am having some styling issues